# How to get the value of a dropdownlist in HTML and pass it to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

So I have two dropdown lists full of values programmed in HTML. Once the user clicks on a selection of one drop down list, I need the value to be passed to a javascript function called searchVector. This is the code I have so far. Apologize in advanced if this is a repost.

```
<li>
   <select name="Industry" id="indy" onchange="accountindustry(value)">
       <option value="">Filter By Industry</option>
       <script language="javascript">drawIndustryList();</script>
   </select>
</li>
<li>
    <select name="ServiceSegment" id="sersec" onchange="accountservicesegment(value)">
       <option value="">Filter By Service Segment</option>
       <script language="javascript">drawServiceList();</script>
    </select>
</li>
```

Comment: if you need to call searchVector(), why are you calling accountindustry() and accountservicesegment() on change?

Comment: If you want to call them both, call for example onchange='function() {accountindustry(value); searchVector(value2); };'

Answer (score 0):

Without using additional libraries, you can pass `this` to the callback:

```
<select name="Industry" id="indy" onchange="accountindustry(this)">
```

and then access the value as:

```
function accountindustry(select_object) {
    var value = select_object.options[select_object.selectedIndex].value;  
}
```

Comment: You can just use `select_object.value`.

Comment: That's right. I knew something was overcomplicated there. Thanks for ponting that out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you're trying to do something like that:

```
<select name="filter" id="filter" onchange="changeFilter(this)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Industry">Filter By Industry</option>
    <option value="ServiceSegment">Filter By Service Segment</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function changeFilter(el) {
         searchVector(el.value);
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

to refer to the current element, use the special variable `this`:

```
<select name="Industry" id="indy" onchange="accountindustry(this.value)">
```

`value` isn't a variable by itself, it's a property of the element.